# AWS opsworks deploy runs for ever after instances are joined to Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I have custom chef 12.2 script to run the deployment on my opsworks, deployment and running recipe used work great on the instances (with Windows Custom AMI - OS server 2012).

Post migration of instances to a Domain. nothing seems to work. 
opsworks agent is running on the instances. not sure what else to look at to solve the issue.

any suggestions how i can investigate the issue and solve it?

**note Reboot from opsworks reboots the instance

Answer (score 0):

whenever opsworks runs for a long time use

```
opsworks-agent-cli show_log
```

command to get  the current activity logs of opsworks agent. if its stuck inside some loop forever, you can get its pid and kill it abruptly.

Comment: Thanks for your response .. unfortunately The AWS OpsWorks Stacks agent on Windows instances does not expose a command-line interface. [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinginstances-os-windows.html)